# Races in Michael Moorcock's multiverse

Tags: michael-moorcock

Where can I find a complete list of sentient races in Michael Moorcock's multiverse? I don't have the opportunity to check all the books right now.

Comment: You might try the [Fandom page for Moorcock's works](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Moorcock%27s_Multiverse_Wikia).  Off-hand I can only think of the Melnibonéans, Eldren, Mabden, Vadhagh and Nadragh.

Comment: Elenoin and Grahluk

Comment: Technically, they would include every possible sentient race, under any conceivable conditions. As I recall, Moorcock's multiverse consisted of random conglomerations of particles that flew together, including whole worlds of people imagining that they had a past of billions of years, before flying apart again. A difficult proposition to refute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Mabden](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Mabden) (humans, etc.)
- [Eldren](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Eldren)
- [Vadhagh](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Vadhagh) (descended from the Eldren)
- [Nadragh](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Nadragh)
- [Melnibonéans](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Melnibon%C3%A9ans)
- [Elenoin](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Elenoin)
- [Grahluk](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Grahluk)